# Converting html page represented as text to dom object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a *text* that represents some page. I need to convert this *text* to dom object, extract `body` element and append it to my dom.

I have used following code to convert text and extract `body` element:

```
$('body', $(text)).length
```

and:

```
$(text).filter('body').length
```

In both cases it returns `0`...

To test:   http://jsfiddle.net/wEyvr/1/

Comment: Could you put your text into a jsfiddle? Your first approach looks valid.

Comment: The second approach looks like it would be valid if you use `find` instead of `filter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is parsing whole HTML in a non-standard way, so `$(html)` doesn't work as expected.

You can extract the content of the body tag using regexp and work from there:

```
// get the content of the body tags
var body = $(text.match(/<body[\s\S]*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/body>/i)[1]);

// append the content to our DOM
body.appendTo('body');

// bonus - to be able to fully use find -> we need to add single parent
var findBody = $("<body />").html(body.clone());

// now we are able to use selectors and have fun
findBody.find("div.cls").appendTo('body');
```

**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/JpY7w/)** is the working code.

EDIT: Changed the code to show both direct append and also using selectors.

Comment: +1 I'd add that it'll be better to try to get the string without the DTD/<html> tag/<head> tag, just the <body> tag to avoid having to pre-process the string before passing it to jQuery. Parsing HTML with regex? Meme ahoy!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var ifr = $("<iframe>"),
    doc = ifr.appendTo("body")[0].contentWindow.document,
    bodyLength;

doc.open();
doc.write(text);
doc.close();

bodyLength = ifr.contents().find("body").length;

ifr.remove();

alert(bodyLength);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wEyvr/2/